# Storing html template as text field in DB using golang

Tags: html, go, go-echo

I'm a beginner in Go and Echo. 
I am required to store a html template(email template) , which will also have some details passed as context. So that it can be stored into body column (text in MySQL) and will be triggered later.

```
if user.Email !=""{
            visitingDetails := H{"user_name"      : user.Fname,
                                 "location"       : location.Name,
                                 "visitor_company": visitor.Company,
                                 "visitor_name"   : visitor.Fname +" "+visitor.Lname,
                                 "visitor_phone"  : visitor.Phone,
                                 "visitor_email"  : visitor.Email,
                                 "visitor_fname"  : visitor.Fname,
                                 "visitor_image"  : visitor.ProfilePicture,
                              }
            subject := visitor.Fname +" has come to visit you at the reception"
            body := c.Render(http.StatusOK,"email/user_notify_email.html",visitingDetails)
            emailJob := models.EmailJob{Recipients: visitor.Email , Subject: subject, Body: body}
            db.Create(&emailJob)
            if db.NewRecord(emailJob){
                fmt.Println("Unable to send email")
            }
        }
```

The EmailJob

```
type EmailJob struct {
    Id              int       
    Recipients      string    
    Subject         string   
    Body            string          
    Sent            int        
    Error           string 
}

func (t *Template) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {
    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}
```

body := c.Render(http.StatusOK,"email/user_notify_email.html",visitingDetails)

this line gives error as it returns an error for render.
I am not sure how I will I do it? I hope I made it clear. A little help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: app/controllers/controllers.go:733:91: cannot use body (type error) as type string in field value   ... This is the error I am getting. @CeriseLimón

Comment: You are looking at the wrong line. The error is in the emailJob assignment. What is c? Presumably c.Render returns an error, not the rendered template.

Comment: C is c echo.Context . And Render func has been mentioned in the details. And yes, I think you're correct, @Peter. It perhaps, executes the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `context.Render` method incorrectly.

https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/context.go#L111

```
// Render renders a template with data and sends a text/html response with status
// code. Renderer must be registered using `Echo.Renderer`.
Render(code int, name string, data interface{}) error
```

The Render methods renders the template and sends it as a response.
This method returns an error value, if something unexpected happens, this error value is a description of it. Otherwise, it is equal to `nil`.
See: https://golang.org/pkg/errors/

In order to use Renderer, you must register it and you can use that **registered renderer** to get rendered template text and save it in DB.

You can see example renderer in unit tests of Echo framework: https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/context_test.go#L23

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @maksadbek, thanks for having a look into the problem. I want that template to be returned as a string value. instead I am getting an error value. This is the problem. And render is registered with echo.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a few things and understanding template in golang. 
I came up with a solution like this.

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/email/user_notify_email.html")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error happend")
            fmt.Println(err)
            return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, data)
        }
        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
        if err = t.Execute(buf, visitingDetails); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        body := buf.String()
```

And now this body can be stored. Body has rendered template that I required. 
Much credit goes to this article https://medium.com/@dhanushgopinath/sending-html-emails-using-templates-in-golang-9e953ca32f3d